# QT drawing without erasing widget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QWidget`-derived class.  In the constructor I say:

```
setPalette(QPalette(QColor(250,250,200)));
setAutoFillBackground(true);
```

Then in my widget's `paintEvent()` I say:

```
QPainter painter(this);
painter.drawRect(1,2,3,4);
```

There is also an `updateNow()` slot...which just calls `update()`.  How can I make sure my palette doesn't get erased after that update call?

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to figure out what you want to know.
Parsing error at line 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have any problems with the following:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPalette>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QPainter>

class Test : public QWidget
{
public:
  Test()
  {
    setPalette(QPalette(QColor(250, 250, 200)));
    setAutoFillBackground(true);
  }

protected:
  virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
  {
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawRect(10, 20, 30, 40);
  }

  virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)
  {
    update();
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  Test myTest;
  myTest.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

The rectangle draws, and stays after I click, which triggers update.  What are you seeing?

Comment: I see it too! But i don't need erasing widget after update(); function. I need to draw new rectangle on top of my widget :)

Comment: @faya . Then in paint event draw "the widget first", then draw "the rect".